# Lagging transitions in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following problem, I want to make a sidebar transition but when I use this code for the transition:

```
sidebar.Width += 15;
```

The result is lagging as if it's like 1 fps. I've used timer to handle the transition. Are there any plugins or setting that I should do to fix it?

Comment: *I've used timer to handle the transition*: post your code, the Timer configuration parameters and specify what is a *sidebar* (what it's made of) and in which context it's used.